# Parsing complex text file using C++

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-studio-2010, text

I have got a task of parsing this text file using c++ code.
I will have to read this file and look for keyword "Results Summary:" and collect entire content after Results Summary: in one variable named as string data; and write the content of data into csv file.
I need help in bringing the content to variable string data...

My text file look like :

textfile.txt: 
 Report file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise\Reports\Export_20190617099828.txt

```
Time log:
---------------------------------------

Time:   9:03:49 AM
Export of archive Walton, Amelia was completed successfully.

End time:   9:03:49 AM


Results Summary:
---------------------------------------

Juma, Jmelia : Processed
Storage server: SRE!
Export = 12; Failed = 0; Remaining = 0 (0%)


Number archives processed:      1
Number archives being processed:    0
Number archives part processed:     0
Number archives not processed:      0
Number archives failed:         0

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to parse this text file and write the data parsed into csv file.

The data to be parsed is :

```
Results Summary:
---------------------------------------

Juma, Jmelia : Processed
Storage server: SRE!
Export = 12; Failed = 0; Remaining = 0 (0%)
```

I have tried in various ways but i am not succeeding.

```
string search = "Results Summary:"
getline(inFile, line); // get line from file
pos = line.find(search); // search
if (pos == string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
{
    WriteLogFile("Found Results Summary:!\n");

    break;
} else {
    WriteLogFile("Not Found string searched for!\n");
}
```

//output:

### below output must be written in .csv file called : test.csv

```
Juma, Jmelia 
Storage server: SRE!
Export = 12; 
Failed = 0;
Remaining = 0 (0%)
```

Comment: expected output is test.csv

Comment: Give sample test output for your input.

Comment: Juma, Jmelia
Storage server: SRE!
Export = 12;
Failed = 0;
Remaining = 0 (0%)   must be printed in csv file

Comment: Could possibly be solved with a *regular expression*.

Answer (score 0):

I wolud do like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
             ifstream input;
        size_t pos;
              string line;
        int found_string=0;
        input.open("t.txt");
        if(input.is_open())
        {
            while(getline(input,line))
            {
                pos = line.find("Results Summary:");
                if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
                {
                    found_string=1;
                    cout <<"Found!";
                }


                if(found_string==1)
                {
                    cout<<line<<endl;
                   //do whatever to save it in the csv
                }

            }
        }

}
```